# Python - Supplying Command Line Arguments - in "from X import A"

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I've been going through various posts to see if this question has been answered. But either I have not been able to understand an answer staring at me or the precise question that I have in my mind has not been asked before.

Question : I created a program called "Filter.py" whose purpose is to accept a file as a command line argument, say "Flags.txt", use this file for doing a large number of "filtrations". eg. An Array A is loaded. A subset A_1 is created satisfying some conditions, A_2 satisfying another set and so on. I want these arrays A_1, A_2 to be available in other programs. So, I say in the other program

```
from Filter import *
```

The above works so long as "Filter.py" is programmed to work even if a command line argument is not provided. Question is - when importing using the above method, can I pass command line arguments?

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear , and there is no restriction
at all to pass any command line arguments >

when you pass any command line arguments you can access them from 
"sys.argv"

Comment: Well. Sorry if I am unable to make the question clear. Let me attempt again. 

A program P accepts A,B and C as command line arguments and these arguments are compulsory i,e. the program needs them at any cost, let's assume.

When executing alone, I could say, 
    `python P.py A B C`

But when in a program Q.py, I say, 
    `from P import *`
the program does not work since A,B and C arguments are not provided. I want to know if something like
    `from P A B C import *` 
is possible?

Comment: No that it is not possible and wrong syntax  , that is 
" from P  A  B  C  import  * "

Comment: `from P A B C import *` - well, I only meant it as an example of what I intended to do. :) Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The best way is to wrap your functionality in a function (let's call it `main`) in your `Filter.py` script which does everything. And add the following:

```
# Filter.py
#...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # ...

    main(some, args)
```

This way, calling from command line:

```
python Filter.py
```

will execute `main`. And if you want to import it in another script (main won't get called):

```
# your other program
import Filter

# ...

Filter.main(some, args)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Well, it looks I have to recode my `Filter.py` program to overcome this limitation. Not sure how many people feel that this is a limitation. I was honestly hoping for something like `from "Filter A B C" import *`. Anyway, now that I know this is not possible, let me get back to altering the code of my program. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, most of the times you need only to refactor your code. Turn a few large functions into more smaller ones, change `sys.argv` to with an array called `arguments` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you have your program set up in Filter.py

But can you just wrap the algorithm in a function and pass the arguments in the function call

eg.

```
from Filter import filter
result = filter(argA, argB, argC)
```

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestion. In reality my program is full of arrays A,B,C,D,E... and codes go something `for i in range(len(A)): if ... ... A_1.append else A_2.append else A_3.append...` (I use Python for data-analysis extensively, hence the large numbers of arrays and filters). Again, thanks for your help.